# syntax error at or near column name while trying insert sql dump

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert a table specific sql dump into a database (psql).
There is a table called "templates" which already has some values, and trying to dump new values. The sql file looks like below.

```
INSERT INTO templates (id, name, created_at, updated_at, template_path, page_type, container_type, entity_type, entity_id, asset_group_id, data_proxy_id, publisher_id, status, default, image_url_path, sequence) VALUES ('434', 'Full Width Image', '2018-10-25 11:13:35.695256', '2018-11-23 07:26:25.663427', '/templates/full_width_landscape', null, null, null, null, null, null, '655', 'true', 'true', 'template1', 1);
```

When I am trying to insert this sql file by doing

```
\i sql file path
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "default"
LINE 1: ...et_group_id, data_proxy_id, publisher_id, status, default, i...
```

Can someone tell what's wrong here ?

Comment: `default` is a reserved word in SQL. Use `"default"` instead, i.e. a _delimited identifier_.

Comment: `default` is a reserved word in SQL.  Use a *different* name, so you don't have conflicts with reserved words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  have use use double quote for reserve word as a column name

```
    INSERT INTO templates (id, name, created_at, updated_at,
 template_path, page_type, container_type,
 entity_type, entity_id, asset_group_id, 
data_proxy_id, publisher_id, status, "default", 
image_url_path, sequence) VALUES ('434', 'Full Width Image', '2018-10-25 11:13:35.695256', '2018-11-23 07:26:25.663427', '/templates/full_width_landscape', null, null, null, null, null, null, '655', 'true', 'true', 'template1', 1);
```